# How can I avoid forms are saved as drafts?

Tags: webforms

I used Drupal 9 webform module to create forms ,
Each form has Submit button and Save as draft button,
Below is the configuration for the form ,
[image]
When I submit the form it save as draft ,

> [image: screenshot]

But when I open it from result section and submit it saved properly without save as a draft .
Is there any setting to stop that?
Is it because of some configuration ?

Comment: You need to provide more info, which form and the steps you used to create it.

Comment: edited Please check , thank you , this is my first question , thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section called *submission draft settings* in the form's settings tab

`/admin/structure/webform/manage/<YOUR_WEBFORM_ID>/settings/submissions`

Comment: yes there is I have only check authenticated user check box that's it . but normally before once I completed the form and submitted that state change draft to complete , I have 20 Q&A on each form , if I partially completed it saved as draft before , but now even if I fully completed it saved as draft .